# Theorem 30.3 of Munkres’ Topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof, second-countable

> Suppose that $X$ has a countable basis. Then: (a) Every open covering of $X$ contains a countable subcollection covering $X$. (b) There exists a countable subset of $X$ that is dense in $X$.

Rephrasing this theorem to my taste:

> Suppose $X$ is second countable. Then: (a) Every open cover of $X$ has a countable subcover. (b) $\exists D\subseteq X$ such that $D$ is countable and $\overline{D}=X$.

**My attempt:**

**(a)** let $U=\{ U_\alpha | \alpha \in J\}$ be an open cover of $X$. $\mathcal{B}=\{ B_n | n\in \Bbb{N}\}$ be countable basis of $\mathcal{T}_X$. $\bigcup_{\alpha \in J} U_\alpha =X$. $\forall x\in X, \exists \alpha_x \in J$ such that $x\in U_{\alpha_x}$. Since $x\in U_{\alpha_x} \in \mathcal{T}_X$, $\exists n_x \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x\in B_{n_x}\subseteq U_{\alpha_x}$. Then $\{ B_{n_x} | x\in X\}$ is countable, since $\{ B_{n_x} | x\in X\} \subseteq \{ B_n | n\in \Bbb{N}\} =\mathcal{B}$, and $ \bigcup_{x\in X} B_{n_x} =X$. Since $| \{ B_{\alpha_x} | x\in X\}|= | \{ U_{\alpha_x} | x\in X\}|$ and $\{ B_{n_x} | x\in X\}$ is countable, $\{ U_{\alpha_x} | x\in X\}\subseteq U$ is countable. $B_{n_x} \subseteq U_{\alpha_x}$, $\forall x\in X$ $\Rightarrow$ $\bigcup_{x \in X} B_{n_x} =X \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in X} U_{\alpha_x}$. So $\bigcup_{x \in X} U_{\alpha_x} =X$. Thus $\exists \{ U_{\alpha_x}| x\in X\}$ countable subcover of $U$. **Is this proof correct?** I find Munkres’ proof little bit vague especially, “For each positive integer $n$ for which it is possible, choose an element $A_n$ of $\mathscr{A}$ containing the basis element $B_n$“ sentence.

**(b)** $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}, \exists x_n \in B_n$, since $B_n \neq \emptyset$ $\forall n\in \Bbb{N}$. Let $D=\{ x_n |n\in \Bbb{N}\}\subseteq X$. Claim: $\overline{D}=X$. Proof: $\overline{D}\subseteq X$ is trivial. Let $x\in X$ and $V\in \mathcal{N}_x$. Since $x\in V\in \mathcal{T}_X$, $\exists m\in \Bbb{N}$ such that $x\in B_m \subseteq V$. So $x_m\in B_m \cap D \subseteq V\cap D$. Thus $V\cap D\neq \emptyset$. Hence $x\in \overline{D}$. Our desired result. **Is this proof correct?**

**Que:** (1) $D$ may be finite(still countable by Munkres definition of countable). (2) Is there any other way to construct set $D$?

Comment: For the concern you raise at the end: If $D$ is finite, then just replace the set $\mathbb{N}$ with the set $\left[\left|D\right|\right]=\{j \in \mathbb{N}: 1 \leq j \leq |D| \}$.

Comment: @MAPelto what if $x_i =c,  \forall \in [|D|]$ and $ x_i=d \neq c$ for some $i\gt |D|$?

Comment: Suppose the basis $\{B_n\}$ consists of only finitely many nonempty subsets. Since $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: B_n \neq \emptyset\}$ is bounded above,  let $M$ be the greatest positive integer such that $B_M \neq \emptyset$. For each $n \in [M]$ choose $x_n$ so that $x_n\in B_n$. Let $D=\{x_n: 1 \leq n \leq M\}$. Suppose $x \in X$. Then every open neighborhood of $x$, $N_x$ satisfies $x \in B_n \subseteq N_x$ for some $n \in [M]$.  Notice this is equivalent to saying that for every open neighborhood, there is $n \in [M]$ so that $x_n \in B_n \cap D \subseteq N_x \cap D$

Comment: @MAPelto yeah. This is more precise.

Comment: Indeed but I don't think there is anything inherently wrong with Munkres' argument as it is written.  Sure it bakes in this detail without talking to the reader much about it but Munkres nonetheless has accounted for it. I think it is good to engage in the reading by being curious about such details.

Comment: I think, my $| \{ B_{\alpha_x} | x\in X\}|= | \{ U_{\alpha_x} | x\in X\}|$ claim is wrong and that’s make entire proof wrong.